# " SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found" when running migration

Tags: sql, laravel, migration, database-migration

I am currently working on a coursework for developing a CMS with Laravel. I did some changes to my pages as I wanted to give them an "position" trait for changing the order. I thought that I can just delete the tables and then run "php artisan migrate" and then seed the table again. Now I am always getting the following error message :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\siggen-cms>php artisan migrate

In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'siggen-cms.pages' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `pages`)  


In Connection.php line 326:

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'siggen-cms.pages' doesn't exist
```

Has anyone a solution for this. All the similar problems on stackoverflow didnt help.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePagesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('url')->unique();
            $table->text('content');
            $table->integer('position')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('pages');
    }
}
```

Comment: when do u get this error is it when you try inserting to the db or when migrating

Comment: I tried around a little bit. Actually every comment with php artisan* ... 
Can it be any dependency in the code like in the views, classes or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help. 
I still don't know the cause of the error but I fixed it. 
I just needed to comment out all the methods in the "RouteServiceProvider".
Anybody has an idea why this was crashing Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of potential problems that could cause this:

1. If you are deleting everything and starting again with a fresh migration, check the position of the migration (based on time / date) to make sure whatever needs this table is **after** the `pages` table is created.
2. More likely based on you saying  "I thought that I can just delete the tables and then run "php artisan migrate", you are not actually creating the table because your migration does not activate for this particular table.  IE the migration has already run for the pages file, according to the database migration table, so this migration file won't be touched.

   a.  To fix this, you can delete the whole db and start from scratch, you can try to roll back the migration(s), or for a quick fix, delete the row in the migrations table where this migration file sits.  IE `SELECT * FROM migrations`, find the `id` for the row where your pages file was migrated, and delete that row.  Then, next time you run `php artisan migrate`, it will create the table.

Comment: I tried all of the above. It seems that I cant do any php artisan commands anymore. You have any experience if it could be some dependencies in the controllers, models or views?
And thank you for your answer :)

Comment: what does `php artisan -v` return when you run it in the terminal?

Comment: That is a different question.  Artisan not working is not the same as why doesn't a single table appear.  Not trying to be mean, just the issues for the table not showing up are resolved in this question (and probably this answer).  For you to figure out why artisan is not working, you should probably ask another question, as you will likely need to put a lot more / different data in the question.  I suggest you ask a different question and include the relevant data to get the artisan thing working - I don't know how to answer that without more information specific to that issue.